# sort words into alphabetic list R

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing unigrams and their frequencies. I would like to split the vector of words alphabetically in an efficient manner. I know that this can be done with `grep`

```
uniPhrase<-unigramDF$phrase[order(unigramDF$phrase)]
as<-uniPhrase[grep(pattern = "^a", x = uniPhrase)]
bs<-uniPhrase[grep(pattern = "^b", x = uniPhrase)]
zs<-uniPhrase[grep(pattern = "^z", x = uniPhrase)]
```

but is there a way to do it with sapply?

Comment: Please show some example data and the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
lst <- setNames(lapply(paste0("^", letters), 
           function(x) uniPhrase[grep(x, uniPhrase)]), paste0(letters, 's'))
```

Or

```
lst2 <- split(uniPhrase, substr(uniPhrase, 1, 1))

names(lst2) <- names(lst)
identical(lst2, lst)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(48)
uniPhrase <- sample(paste0(letters, rep(paste0('word', 1:10), each=26)), 
         100, replace=TRUE)
```